# PostgreSQL function to insert record not working as intended

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a function to create a user (insert record into table USERS) if the user does not exist.  The version of PostgreSQL that I am running is:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.24 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28), 64-bit
```

The table USERS has the following columns:

```
id serial primary key
,username text
,password_hash text
```

I have a function created that will return a userid for a given username.  If the username doesn't exist then it returns 0, else a valid userid will be returned.  This function (in my USER_DATA schema) is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_data.get_user_id(
    p_username text)
RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE user_id int;
BEGIN

    IF exists(select distinct id from user_data.users where username = p_username) THEN
        SELECT distinct id INTO user_id
        FROM user_data.users
        WHERE username = p_username;
    ELSE
        user_id = 0;
    END IF;

    RETURN user_id;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am now working on a function to create a user if GET_USER_ID returns 0.  The three possible return values are:

```
TRUE - if user is created
FALSE - if username already exists and user is not created
ERROR - if there is any type of error
```

When testing this function, these are my results:

Running when user already exists: FALSE  <-- this is expected

Running when user does not exist: ERROR  <-- this is not expected.

Can anyone provide insight as to why I might be getting an error with the following logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_data.create_user(in p_username text, p_password_hash text)
returns text AS $$
DECLARE 
    v_user_created text;
    v_user_id int;
    v_error text;

BEGIN
    select user_data.get_user_id(p_username) into v_user_id;

    IF v_user_id = 0 THEN

        insert into user_data.users(username, password_hash) values (p_username, p_password_hash);
        commit;
        v_user_created := 'TRUE';
    ELSE
        v_user_created := 'FALSE';
    END IF;

    RETURN v_user_created;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN
    v_error := 'ERROR';
    RETURN v_error;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



select user_data.create_user('new_user', 'sample_password_not_hashed');
```

Any help, insight, or criticism is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You really should simplify that `get_user_id` function to return `COALESCE((SELECT distinct id
        FROM user_data.users
        WHERE username = p_username), 0)`

Comment: If your goal is to prevent duplicate usernames your function won't do that with concurrent inserts. The only proper way to ensure that is a unique index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `COMMIT` inside `create_user` is not necessary.

```
IF v_user_id = 0 THEN
    insert into users(username, password_hash) values (p_username, p_password_hash);
    --commit;
    v_user_created := 'TRUE';
ELSE
    v_user_created := 'FALSE';
END IF;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e8153b302cc337cb009a7e3412575ae0)**

Comment: That was the problem.  Upon reading the documentation it seems that the function itself is a compete transaction and commit is implicit.  Thank you for your help!